# Rails Routing: Two actions to point to the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm trying to create two actions that both go to the "new" view.  The only difference is I would like the new_e_drawing action to run the incrament_e method, whereas the new action runs the incrament method.

```
  def new
    @drawing = Drawing.new
    @drawing = @drawing.incrament(@drawing)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @drawing }
    end
  end

  def new_e_drawing
    @drawing = Drawing.new
    @drawing = @drawing.incrament_e(@drawing)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html  new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @drawing }
    end
  end
```

I would like both of them to take me to the view named "new".  I'm not sure how to set up the routing or the respond_to statement for the new_e_drawing action.  I tried these with no success:

```
 get 'drawings/new' => 'drawings#new_e_drawing'
 match 'drawings/new_e_drawing' => 'drawings#new_e_drawing'
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `@drawing.incrament(@drawing)` ? why are passing the object on which you are calling the method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Render the "new" template explicitly in your html block of new_e_drawing action.

```
 def new
    @drawing = Drawing.new
    @drawing = @drawing.incrament(@drawing)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @drawing }
    end
  end

  def new_e_drawing
    @drawing = Drawing.new
    @drawing = @drawing.incrament_e(@drawing)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :template => "new" }
      format.json { render json: @drawing }
    end
  end
```

In your routes,

```
match 'drawings/new_e_drawing' => 'drawings#new_e_drawing'
```

route for new action will be automatically generated by rails since it is part of CRUD

Comment: When I try this i get the following error `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DrawingsController#show

Couldn't find Drawing with id=new_e_drawing`

Comment: Add `match 'drawings/new_e_drawing' => 'drawings#new_e_drawing'` to the top of your routes.rb

Comment: Great! I just had to change the template to "drawings/new" after moving the route to the top.